# ActiveRecord Scope: Strange behaviour with select on relation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two different models with a 1:N relation.
Let's name them 'myobject' and 'related'

```
class Myobject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :related
  scope :without_related, includes(:related).select{ |o| o.related.size == 0 }
end
class Related < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The defined scope seems to work great as long as I don't create new assignments from Myobjects to Related:

- Direct rails c command "Myobject.includes(:related).select ... (as defined in Scope) works as expected
- Calls to scope "Myobject.without_related" still return objects that have been assigned in the meantime

It seems that this can be fixed by restarting the rails console or restarting Webrick.
But I can't always restart a webapplication only because a relation between objects has been changed ;)

Is there any way to fix this problem or to write the scope in a better way?

PS: I need this query as scope to pass its name as group_method to a grouped_select in the form of the Myobject model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use counter_cache for this, you need to add column *related_count* of type int to Myobject, make migration and then you will be able to do so:

```
class Myobject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :related
  scope :without_related, where(related_count: 0)
end

class Related < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :myobject, counter_cache: true
end
```

After that you will have super fast scope for getting all objects with no related records and  an a count of that objects as well

Comment: Just forgot about this rails feature. Sometimes simple is the best ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that in fact your scope is not scope :)

Scopes must return relations, but your scope returns array.

Though it can work as you expect, if you wrap it in lambda

```
 scope :without_related, lambda{ includes(:related).select{ |o| o.related.size == 0 } }
```

But I recommend to rewrite this code as usual class method to not mislead those who'll work with this code in future

```
def self.without_related
  includes(:related).select{ |o| o.related.size == 0 }
end
```

or use counter cache, as advised in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you know column name that should be present in related table, use this definition:

```
class Myobject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :related
  scope :without_related, includes(:related).where('related.id', true)
end
```